# How to open custom view and bottom sheet in tabbar views and Subview with sticky bottom tabbar in SWIFTUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabbar, bottom-sheet, swiftui-navigationstack

Given code is for **custom bottom tab-bar** with plus button in center by using we need to hide and show one detail view and from last tab we are just opens menu from bottom sheet.

Problem :- When we are hide and show a detail view using center button that refresh the ui and **redirect us on root from any subview.** while we are using bottom sheet that works fine for us.
When we are open bottom sheet in subview that is start view from top of tabbar.

[Problem Video](https://www.veed.io/view/677af25e-4342-4f9c-8120-200b64100617/showcase?sharingWidget=true)

```
import SwiftUI

struct DashboardTBV: View {
    @StateObject var manager = CalendarManager()
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter = ViewRouter()
    @State var showTimerDetail : Bool = false
    @State var showToast : Bool = false
    @State var toastMsg : String = ""
    let layout = [
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    @State var showWorkOrderList : Bool = false
    @State var month : String = ""
    @State var year : String = ""
    @State var filterDate : String = ""
    
    @State var spacing: CGFloat = 20
    @State var headspace: CGFloat = 15
    @State var sidesScaling: CGFloat = 0.8
    @State var isWrap: Bool = false
    @State var autoScroll: Bool = false
    @State var time: TimeInterval = 1
    @State var currentIndex: Int = 0
    @State var isLoading : Bool = true
    @State var popToRoot : Bool = false
    @State var showSheet : Bool = false
    @State var showProfile : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Spacer()
                ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    VStack {
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                    .background(Constant.AppColors.dark_background.opacity((showTimerDetail) ? 0.3 : 0))
                    .zIndex(5)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.showTimerDetail = false
                        }
                    }
                    VStack(spacing:0) {
                        switch viewRouter.currentPage {
                        case .home:
                            VStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Home")
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        case .setting:
                            VStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Liked")
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        case .notification:
                            VStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Records")
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        case .profile:
                            Text("")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        HStack {
                            DashboardTabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .home, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "home", tabName: "")
                            DashboardTabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .setting, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "Time-Circle", tabName: "")
                            ZStack {
                                
                            }
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/8, height: geometry.size.width/8)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .offset(y: -55)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    showTimerDetail.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                            DashboardTabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .notification, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "Chat", tabName: "")
                            DashboardTabBarIcon(viewRouter: viewRouter, assignedPage: .profile, width: geometry.size.width/5, height: geometry.size.height/28, systemIconName: "Category", tabName: "xyz") {
                                self.showSheet = true
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 110)
                        .riseShadow()
                        .zIndex(10)
                    }
                    
                    if showTimerDetail {
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Time Clock")
                                    .foregroundColor(Constant.AppColors.iPoint_orange)
                                    .font(.custom(Constant.Font.Biotif_Medium, size: 20))
                                Spacer()
                            }.padding()
                            Divider()
                                .background(Constant.AppColors.white)
                                .frame(height: 0.6)
                            HStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Clocked In at: 8/25/2022 9:41:52 AM")
                                    .foregroundColor(Constant.AppColors.white)
                                    .font(.custom(Constant.Font.Biotif_Regular, size: 16))
                                Spacer()
                            }.padding()
                            
                            Button {
                                withAnimation {
                                    
                                }
                            } label: {
                                HStack {
                                    Text("Clock Out")
                                        .font(.custom(Constant.Font.Biotif_SemiBold, size: 16))
                                        .foregroundColor(Constant.AppColors.dark_background)
                                }
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .frame(height: 50)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Constant.AppColors.white)
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                            .padding()
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 30)
                        .background(Constant.AppColors.dark_background)
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing])
                        .padding(.bottom, 110)
                        .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)))
                        .zIndex(6)
                        
                    }
                    ZStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width/15, height: geometry.size.width/15)
                            .foregroundColor( self.showTimerDetail ? Constant.AppColors.iPoint_orange : Constant.AppColors.white)
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(self.showTimerDetail ? 180.0 : 0.0))
                    }
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width/8, height: geometry.size.width/8)
                    .background(Constant.AppColors.dark_background)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .offset(y: -85)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            showTimerDetail.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    .zIndex(100)
                }
                PushView(destination: ProfileView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all), destinationId: "ProfileView", isActive: $showProfile) {
                    Text("")
                        .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                }
            }
            .modifier(MenuBottomSheet(showClose: false , isVisible: $showSheet))
        }
    }
}


struct DashboardTabBarIcon: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    let assignedPage: Page
    let width, height: CGFloat
    let systemIconName, tabName: String
    var tapAction : (()->())?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemIconName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
                .padding(.top, 30)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, -4)
        .onTapGesture {
            if tabName == "" {
                viewRouter.currentPage = assignedPage
            } else {
                tapAction?()
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(viewRouter.currentPage == assignedPage ? .selectedTabBarIconColor : .unSelectedTabBarIconColor)
    }
}
```

Comment: You put tapgesture showDetails twice ? Also , in your case tap’ame parameter is not very use full : testing if tapAction is nil or not will do the job.

Comment: I removed that unused tap action from tabbar but nothing changed in behaviour. @PtitXav